# PHP String to JSON error

Tags: php, json

I have the following object as a string in PHP returned from a database.

```
 string(4385) 
   "[
       {
            "field_key":"first_name",
            "general_setting":
                  {
                      "label":"First Name",
                      "description":"",
                      "field_name":"first_name",
                      "placeholder":"First Name",
                      "required":"yes",
                      "hide_label":"no"
                  },
            "advance_setting":{}
        },
        {
            "field_key":"last_name",
            "general_setting":
                  {
                      "label":"Last Name",
                      "description":"",
                      "field_name":"last_name",
                      "placeholder":"First Name",
                      "required":"yes",
                      "hide_label":"no"
                  },
            "advance_setting":{}
        }
  ]"
```

When I decode the json using http://freeonlinetools24.com/json-decode , I get the error

```
Invalid JSON format!! Unable to process your request.
```

I need to remove the text string(4385) and quotes from the string for it to work correctly.

I want to be able to loop round each  object and output each label

Comment: Are you using print_r instead of print?

Comment: *It is not being recognised as a JSON object. Can any help me make it a JSON object ?* What errors are you getting? What have you tried? the `string(4385)` is just the type and length of the vardump.

Comment: Sites like https://jsonlint.com/ can help you work out if there is something wrong with the JSON.

Comment: *"Can any help me make it a JSON object ?"* -- use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), don't reinvent the wheel (most probably it won't be round enough to roll.)

Comment: "I am trying to encode it as JSON "...how? Just use `json_encode()` to do it reliably. There is no reason to write your own serialiser.

Comment: some semantics. There is no such thing as a PHP json object. JSON is typically a string (as you have) that represents an object. So , you should not json_encode the string, but rather json_decode it. Please **[Read The Fabulous Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)**, and dont forget the second parameter.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification. Now we know you're trying to **decode** not **encode** - try to use the right terminology otherwise we end up going down blind alleys. Anyway, how is this online tool relevant to your actual application code? You realise what you've shown above is merely the result of visualising your string using `var_dump()`? If you were doing this in code, that part wouldn't be there. If this data is contained in a string variable, the `json_decode()` function should be able to process this into a PHP object / array without a problem. See https://eval.in/1030469 for a demo

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion  . please stop changing the question, it is very hard to help you with a moving target.

Comment: You (or someone) seem to have saved an invalid JSON string. For now you can manually rectify this by just keeping the part of the string within the outer quotes and then ensure this never happens again by saving the json string and not a var_dump of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its a string value you can use json_decode:

```
$test='[
       {
            "field_key":"first_name",
            "general_setting":
                  {
                      "label":"First Name",
                      "description":"",
                      "field_name":"first_name",
                      "placeholder":"First Name",
                      "required":"yes",
                      "hide_label":"no"
                  },
            "advance_setting":{}
        },
        {
            "field_key":"last_name",
            "general_setting":
                  {
                      "label":"Last Name",
                      "description":"",
                      "field_name":"last_name",
                      "placeholder":"First Name",
                      "required":"yes",
                      "hide_label":"no"
                  },
            "advance_setting":{}
        }
  ]';
  $test=json_decode($test);
  print_r($test);
die;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score -3):

There is another way, try to put it in php variable,encode it before return. Check out php manual 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.phpecho

```
json_encode("$elm");
```

Then use jquery to make change

Comment: Why the quote marks (`"`) round `"$elm"`? Seems unnecessary. other than that...certainly using json_encode() would be the way to encode an object as JSON when using PHP, but at the time of writing we don't actually yet know what the OP is actually doing currently, or precisely where they're having a problem really - the question details are unclear.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it should not have ". Just put php variable in it

Comment: you can edit it, then. But see the edited question, this answer is not relevant. Better to delete it really.

Comment: this my first time to comment, don't be too stress lol. and in return because been helped yesterday on my code, i just want to help other. just check the structure of json code. here the linkhttps://json.org/example.html. for the first "{" should have variable right. for example, "menu": { .....} , same as second one.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to say. The question has been updated and clarified - read it. OP is trying to **decode** not **encode**. Your answer was only partially relevant to be begin with, but now it needs changing much more.